# Is "No significant evidence for $X$" the same as "(Significant?) evidence for (Not $X$)"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In statistical Hypothesis testing, let's say we are testing for a change in a test statistic, for example, the change in proportion of the population that are over 45 years old, although the test statistic could be anything. The test is done from a sample of the population, and the sample proportion is compared to the known proportion of the population.

Let's say the conclusion of the hypothesis test is, "there is no (significant) evidence to support the claim that the proportion of the population that are over $45$ years old has changed". My question is, is this the exact same as saying, "There is (significant?) evidence that the proportion of the population that are over $45$ years old has not changed" ? Or what about, "There is (significant?) evidence that the proportion of the population that are over $45$ years old has not changed *by much*" ?

Comment: "there is no significant evidence to support the claim that the proportion of the population that are over 45 years old has changed" is **not equivalent** to "There is significant evidence that the proportion of the population that are over 45 years old has not changed"

Comment: "The evidence suggests with 95% confidence that the proportion of the population that are over 45 years old appears has changed by less than 0.2, if at all" may be something you can say using confidence intervals

Comment: @Henry ok so you'd have to do infinitely many hypothesis tests. One of them would be: "Under assumption that the proportion has increased by $0.3$, the probability of the observed result is $p_1$." And then not just do this for $+0.3, $ but for every change in proportion that is outside the interval $[p-0.2, p+0.2]$ ? And then sum these up in some sort of integral (or find the average of the $p_i$?), and then if the sum/average is less than $5$ % then you can conclude with the affirmative evidence for a $95$% confidence interval. Is this correct?

Comment: No - if your 95% confidence interval for the change is $[-0.2,+0.3]$ or if your confidence interval is $[+0.1,+0.3]$ then you can (with the usual technical interpretation of confidence intervals) that the evidence suggests the change is that small (assuming 0.3 is a small change in the context you are looking at).  Note that the second confidence interval is consistent with statistically significant evidence of change while the first is not.